# Delete data based on the count & timestamp using pl\sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm new to PL\SQL programming and I'm from DBA background. I got one requirement to delete data from both main table and reference table but need to follow below logic while deleting data because we need to delete 30M of data from the tables so we're reducing data based on the "State_ID" column below.

Following conditions need to consider
1. As per sample data given below(Main Table), sort data based on timestamp with desc order and leave the first 2 rows of data for each "State_id" and delete rest of the data from the both tables based on "state_id" column.
2. select state_id,count(*) from maintable group by state_id order by timestamp desc Having count(*)>2;

So if state_id=1 has 5 rows then has to delete 3 rows of data by leaving first 2 rows for state_id=1 and repeat for other state_id values.

Also same matching data should be deleted from the reference table as well.

Please someone help me on this issue. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgAQl.png)

Main table

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do each table delete as a single SQL command. Anything else would essentially force row-by-row processing, which is the last thing you want for that much data. Something like this:

```
delete from main_table m
where m.row_id not in (
    with keep_me as (
        select row_id, 
               row_number() over (partition by state_id 
                                      order by time_stamp desc) id_row_number 
          from main_table where id_row_number<3)
    select row_id from keep_me)
```

or

```
delete from main_table m 
where m.row_id in (
    with delete_me as (
        select row_id, 
               row_number() over (partition by state_id 
                                      order by time_stamp desc) id_row_number 
        from main_table where id_row_number>2)
    select row_id from delete_me)
```